# How can I transform 12 Volt DC to 17 Volt AC?

Tags: power, ac, dc, battery-operated

I am new to electronics and me and my friend want to build a big speaker out of some old small ones.

We are going to use a subwoofer from PC speakers as main speaker, but there is a problem. We are going to use a car battery to power this thing, that gives 12V DC. The subwoofer, however, uses 17V AC.

Is there a way to use the power from the car battery to power this subwoofer?

Like transformating the power? Or will it harm the subwoofer?

Comment: The speaker doesn't use 17VAC. The amplifier in the speaker uses 17VAC. Work out what you *actually* want to do.

Comment: *How can I transform 12 Volt DC to 17 Volt AC?* You cannot, transformers only convert AC to AC. Probably what you mean is: the subwoofer needs a mains adapter which provides 17 V AC. This is rectified internally to a DC voltage and that powers the amplifier. Very likely this subwoofer will just work if you feed it 12 V DC. You could just try that, I'd put a 1 A fuse in series with the 12V DC thoug, if that blows then the subwoofer does not like that 12 V DC. But if it works it works.

Comment: @FakeMoustache You can convert DC to AC using an Inverter. But it seems strange to me that the subwoofer power input takes 17VAC...I would double and triple check to verify that is actually the case.

Comment: @FakeMoustache well, on the transformator that converts the socket power it says: "Output 17V AC" and it directly runs into the circuit

Comment: @FakeMoustache Here a pic of the transformator: http://i.imgur.com/pyJRnf3.jpg
the blue wires run directly into the circuit

Comment: @crowie *You can convert DC to AC using an Inverter.* Of course I know that but the question was about transforming the voltage. I was taking that literally.

Comment: It is unclear how many wires there are. Are there 2 blue wires ? Then you stand a chance, **disconnect the transformer** (the tranformer will short DC and blow the fuse I suggested you use) and try 12 V dc on those wires. Are there **three** blue wires: then you can forget about using 12 V DC directly.

Comment: @FakeMoustache there are two blue wires, but there is also a black one coming from underneath the PCB. I don't know if that is a problem? You can see it here: http://i.imgur.com/g4bGqkC.jpg

Comment: My guess is that the black wire is for grounding/shielding. The ampl will also work without that when operating from a DC voltage. I see that the transformer is connected via a white connector. You can just disconnect that and put 12 V DC on those connectors (with the fuse I mentioned !) and check if that makes the amplifier work. There's only one large capacitor (the black/aluminium cylinder) so so this looks like a single supply amplifier, which is good for your purpose.

Comment: Even better would be to connect the 12 V DC **directly** (but again via a fuse) to that large capacitor, do mind the polarity, the capacitor has a clear - (minus) indication. This is the main supply decoupling capacitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty certain that the amplifier (we're not talking about the subwoofer as speaker, we're talking about the amplifier – the subwoofer itself is passive, ie. just the thing that converts an electrical audio signal directly to air pressure changes) internally uses DC.

You'll very likely find a diode bridge rectifier right after the point where the 17 VAC enter the PCB. Probe the DC voltage at the big capacitors coming after that rectifier! That's the DC voltage you'll need to supply.

If that voltage is not 12 V (and it probably isn't) you'll either need a step-down converter (target voltage < 12 V) or a step-up converter (target voltage > 12 V). It's not terribly hard to build one, even for audio applications with OK noise properties (especially since your subwoofer won't even care about noise >1kHz at all).

Now, big speaker systems do need quite some power. Your transformer is rated for a little more than 40 W (effective voltage * current) – that probably leaves some headroom that you won't fully need, but it's still going to be a relatively solid power supply you might be building.

If you're lucky, the rectifying circuit is designed in a way that gives you close to 12V as target voltage, or just a few volt above. In that case, simply remove the transformer and directly power with the battery (at the point where you probed the voltage).

All in all, as said, the PCB looks dated. That means the amplifier is probably of a "classical" design – which might be a very good design in some respect, but it guarantees that it's not very power-efficient. In your case, that's bad for two reasons:

1. your battery won't last long, and
2. your step-up or step-down power supply need to be capable of providing more power.

In effect, it might actually be easier to get a bare-PCB class D/E amplifier that directly works off 12V – I, for example, use exactly such a device to power speakers when going on festivals. They're available for a couple of bucks on the usual websites.

---

## Edit

With your photo of the power supply PCB, we can be more detailed:

[image: Foto of power PCB]

You correctly labeled the Diodes already!

The circuit they form is this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQf5ar.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The component numbering doesn't necessarily match your board (can't see how the traces run under the diodes). Notice that the big "cylinder" right of the diodes is probably the capacitor I keep mentioning.

Comment: Ok, so I took a look and I don't really know where I should put my cables then. So Here are the images of the circuit, could you point out where I should connect the battery if there is a Diode Bridge Rectifier?

http://i.imgur.com/g4bGqkC.jpg

http://i.imgur.com/neOYp3Q.jpg

Comment: Ok, so I went browsing a bit and found this board with everything with the things pointed out (http://i.imgur.com/UOGUToa.jpg). It is not the same as mine, but very similar. I see DC but also AC, I really have no clue were to put the DC now, please help.

Comment: @Ablos does my edit help?

Comment: Yes! Thanks! But do I need to hook up the battery after the diodes or the capicitor? That wasn't clear for me yet. And where needs to be the plus and where the minus?

Comment: look at my schematic, @Ablos. as you can see, the output of the diodes is the same as what the capacitor is attached to. And polarity is depicted in my schematic, too, and even your cap has a  grey stripe on one side that denotes the negate pole, typically. And since you've measured the voltage, you'll know the polarity, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

12VDC to Mains voltage AC power (can be 100V to 240V depending on what country you are in) Invertors are very common and you can buy these quite easily.

However if in fact this particular subwoofer takes 17VAC 50/60Hz power input then you would need an additional Step down transformer to get you from Mains voltage to 17VAC which you can also buy. But you might not be able to find 17V exactly but something close like 16V or 18-24V.

Be sure to take note of the power requirements of your sub so to match up the ratings of the Inverter and step down transformer.

Edit: Now that I have seen the picture of the transformer inside your sub you need a 12VDC to 230/240VAC Inverter.